# TFS Query to show work items where their resolving changeset is in trunk

Tags: tfs

When we as devs make a commit we associate to a work item (bug) and the default state is resolved. So if this work item happens to be a bug, then TFS will assign it back to the creator requiring them to accept it.

This is all well and good, but say it's the team testing UAT that are logging these bugs in TFS. They have no view on whether the changeset that resolved the bug has made it into the trunk. It could be anywhere in the repository. Only every other day do we manually merge the dev branch into the trunk, which auto deploys to the UAT server.

In visual studio I can track a changeset in timeline mode and see that it made it into the truck. But is there a way to filter this in a query, for all bugs that are assigned to the current user, but only that have a changeset that's made it into trunk?

Would appreciate if someone knows how to do this through the web access, or something similar. If not I might try writing something that uses the API but this means circumventing the TFS site altogether which would be a shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't do this via a Work Item Query.  You will have to use the TFS API to do it.  You can expose the information either via a custom tool or via an SSRS report.

At this time TFS Web Access does not support customization, so there is no easy way to expose it in TFS Web Access.

Some tools have figured out how to customize/extend web access (e.g. Urban Turtle), but they use an undocumented and unsupported method (I think Urban Turtle does this by injecting a custom HttpModule via IIS).